# Symfony _defaults in bundles

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm a newbie in Symfony and have a few questions about the dependency injection, particularly about Symfony 3.3

1. Can the new `_defaults` block be declared for every single bundle separately or it's global and defined in the hosting app?
2. Can I use [the new things](http://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#auto-tagging-with-autoconfigure) like autowiring in my reusable bundles or I have to declare all the bundle's services separately?

Comment: From https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-simpler-service-configuration#default-service-configuration "The new services._defaults option lets you set the value of the public, tags and autowire options for all the services defined in a single file:" Note the phrase "single file"  So yes, each reusable bundle can still have their own services.yaml file with it's own set of defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's per file declaration. You can also override it at single service definitions. E.g.

   ```
   # app/config/services.yml
   services:
       _defaults:
           autowire: true

       App\SomeService:
           autowire: false
   ```
2. In short: yes.

---

I feel you're asking **how to combine all this features together** and **what is the best practise for it**. Saying that, I'll extend my answer with multi-bundle example of service definitions.

#### Application with 2 Bundles would look like this

```
imports:
    - { resource: "../../src/FirstBundle/config/services.yml" }
    - { resource: "../../src/SecondBundle/config/services.yml" }

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\SomeService:
        autowire: false
```

With first bundle:

```
# src/FirstBundle/config/services.yml

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\FirstBundle\:
        resource: ../..
```

And second bundle:

```
# src/SecondBundle/config/services.yml

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\SecondBundle\:
        resource: ../..
```

#### One Extra Tip

Also, you can improve first file to **just single line import** thanks to [glob patterns](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-import-config-files-with-glob-patterns).

I [use it in practise](https://github.com/RectorPHP/Rector/blob/0cf5680e729965d356cf17f502e1c854e7025e5d/src/config/config.yml#L1-L3) like this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: "../../src/**/config/services.yml" }

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\SomeService:
        autowire: false
```

You can read more about **Symfony 3.3 dependency-injection features** in [this post with before/after config examples](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/).